# Pure name equivalence in type checking

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, programming-languages, compatibility, typechecking

I am reading Ravi Sethi's book about the programming language concepts, and there it says

> ```
> int *i1;  
> int *i2;
> ```
>
> After these declarations, the types of i1 and i2 are not name type compatible. In 
>       a language that uses name type compatibility, variables i1 and i2 could not be
>       compared or assigned to each other.

I wonder why are not they name compatible? They have the same name type:int. Can somebody explain this and give an example of a valid pure name equivalence? Thanks

Comment: In the context of C++, I don't think this makes any sense...

Comment: Is this an excerpt of the book by any chance? http://users.dickinson.edu/~wahlst/356/ch5.pdf

Comment: @JBentley yes, there is the example

Comment: His context seems to be this: `A type constructor is an operator that builds new types. For example, in C++ the type constructors
include: [], struct, class, union and *.` and `Name Type Compatibility [...] 2. no constructed type (expression containing a type constructor) is compatible with any other`. Perhaps that will help someone else answer your question.

Comment: So, why are i1 and i2 are incompatible in his context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of them has the type `int`.  Both are typed as pointer to `int`. I think Sethi's point is that in a hypothetical language using (only) name equivalence, these two pointer-to-`int` type expressions create two different types that are not compatible – much like two identical uses of `new` create distinct, non-equivalent objects.

In a name equivalence language, you have to give a name to a type expression to use it more than once type-compatibly.  In C++ syntax, that would require using `typedef`:

```
typedef int *intp;
intp i1;
intp i2;
```

Now, `i1` and `i2` have name-compatible types.